# Colocar primeiro resultado com margem maior que os outros

Tags: css

Oi, minha dúvida é meio estranha, sempre coloquei no css dois ids para quando coloco uma margem, o primeiro com margem 20px e o segundo com margem 10px, queria saber se tem algum jeito de fazer isso automaticamente, segue exemplo pois esse texto explicativo esta péssimo!!!

Exemplo:

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qvMC8/)**

HTML:

```
<div id="contato-texto">Nome:</div>
<div id="contato-texto2">Nome:</div>
<div id="contato-texto2">Nome:</div>
<div id="contato-texto2">Nome:</div>
```

CSS:

```
#contato-texto {
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 20px;
font-family: OratorStd;
color: #e4d88a;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: left;
}
#contato-texto2 {
margin-top: 5px;
margin-left: 20px;
font-family: OratorStd;
color: #e4d88a;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma boa regra é fazer o que é comum primeiro e depois o que é unico. Assim podia comprimir esse CSS para isto:

```
#contato-texto, #contato-texto2 {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-family: OratorStd;
    color: #e4d88a;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
}
#contato-texto2 {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use uma div externa:

```
<div id="contato-texto">
    <div>Nome:</div>
    <div>Nome:</div>
    <div>Nome:</div>
    <div>Nome:</div>
</div>
```

E no CSS:

```
#contato-texto > div {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#contato-texto {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-family: OratorStd;
    color: #e4d88a;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qvMC8/2/)

Vale observar que o id deve ser **único** na página. Usar um único ID mais de uma vez na mesma página torna o seu HTML inválido.